# How to get relationship diagram of primary and foreign key in two tables of a database in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a doubt about sql server: how to get primary and foreign keys 
of relationship of 2 tables in sql server except the way `sp_help table name`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com) to generate a textual representation of your database schema including relationships indicated by foreign keys. You will need to install a Java runtime, though.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)